# Customize check in recycleview -kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have the following question and I have no idea how to do it.
How could I customize the checkboxes of each item of my recycleview, in this way.

Example how you want to get the view:

[image]

But when running my project and listing my questions in my recycleview this shows with 1 single layout for all questions.

**this is my adapter.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/borderelative"
        android:padding="6dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtnumeropregunta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

            android:text="N°"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtpreguntas"
            android:layout_width="320dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtnumeropregunta"
            android:text="Preguntas"
            android:autoSizePresetSizes="@array/autosize_text_sizes"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icosemaforo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtpreguntas"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop ="@+id/contenedor_cabecera"
        android:id="@+id/contenedor_categoria1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        >

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/check_si" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="@string/check_na"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

**this is my adapter.kt**

```
    class listadapterpreuso(private val context : Context,
                        private val listpreguntas:ArrayList<epreguntas>,
                        private val itemClickListener: OnListPreguntasClickListener
): RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<*>>() {

    interface OnListPreguntasClickListener{
        fun onItemClick(
            numpregunta:String,
            pregunta: String

        )
    }

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BaseViewHolder<*> {
    return PreguntasViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_estructura_listapreuso,parent,false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BaseViewHolder<*>, position: Int) {
    when(holder){
        is PreguntasViewHolder -> holder.bind(listpreguntas[position],position)
        else -> IllegalArgumentException("SE OLVIDO")
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = listpreguntas.size

inner class PreguntasViewHolder(itemView: View) : BaseViewHolder<epreguntas>(itemView){
    override fun bind(item:epreguntas,position: Int){
        itemView.setOnClickListener{itemClickListener.onItemClick(item.num_pregunta,item.pregunta)}
        Glide.with(context).load(item.icono_estado).into(itemView.icosemaforo)

        itemView.txtnumeropregunta.text =item.num_pregunta
        itemView.txtpreguntas.text = item.pregunta

    }
}
```

}

**and this is my listapruso.kt where i call my recycleview**

```
    class listapreuso : AppCompatActivity(),listadapterpreuso.OnListPreguntasClickListener {
    var sp = spreguntas()
var listado : ArrayList<epreguntas> = ArrayList()
private val scro by bind<ScrollView>(R.id.miscroll)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listapreuso)
    val toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar4)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    setuprecycleview()
    supportActionBar?.apply {
        // show back button on toolbar
        // on back button press, it will navigate to parent activity
        setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
    }
}
private fun setuprecycleview(){
    recycleviewpreguntas.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recycleviewpreguntas.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL))
     listado  = sp.listarpreguntas(Conexiones.listarpreguntas)
    recycleviewpreguntas.adapter = listadapterpreuso(this,listado,this)
}
```

but in the end it is shown in this way it only shows me 1 single design pattern for all the questions which does not comply with what they asked for in class, I want it to be shown as the image start the checkboxes randomly since each question has different answers.

[image]

Comment: You're only using one layout file, and that layout doesn't have a *No* checkbox in it, so what were you expecting? Since this is for a class I'm not going to just give you the code to do it (you'll have to write that yourself), but you basically have two options - either use two different kinds of `ViewHolder`, with their own layouts, or use a single `ViewHolder` and just reconfigure it to display different kinds of item. Since your layouts are so similar, that's probably your best option. Add the *No* checkbox, give it an *id*, then make it visible/invisible in `onBindViewHolder` as required

Comment: According to the scenario that you recommend, there are 2 scenarios. Could you add a "No" checkbox and then make it visible, in the questions that will be needed?

Comment: `ViewHolder`s get reused in a `RecyclerView` (that's the reason for the name) so in `onBindViewHolder` you get a VH that's probably been used to display another item *earlier*. So you need to set it up to clean it up, and display everything correctly for the *current* item - and that can include making that checkbox visible (or invisible!) and setting its checked state. You'll have to work out whether the current item should show the box or not, I don't know what the logic is. If it's just alternating (display it for odd numbers / even indices) then you can use `val show = position % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's Just an idea. not a solution.**

I don't know it's work or not but try this.

Take one parameter in your Model Class.

```
var checkBoxCount = 0
```

**Initialized `checkBoxCount` with your data. And manage it to your xml file. with visibility**

For e.g

if you have 2 checkbox with contain `yes` and `NA` in your data. then make condition like this.

```
if(checkBoxCount == 2){
     cbYes.visibility = View.Visible 
     cbNo.visibility = View.InVisible 
     cbNA.visibility = View.Visible 
}
```

Manage it with `Visible` or `Invisible`. Don't Use `Gone`.

Comment: This looks good, I'm going to check this idea and tell you how it went.

Comment: The idea you indicated was the right one for me, you saved my day, thank you.